# How to scale UV map?

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to position a UV map over an image, but I cannot figure out how to scale the x and y dimensions independent of each other. As you can see from the picture, I need to scale the y dimension to fit the eye. When I loaded the image inside of the *UV Editor*, the UV maps became distorted.

[image]

Comment: If you load in textures that are square(power of 2) this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do it the same way as everywhere else, by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> followed by the axis you want to scale on, i.e. <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Additionally you can press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + the axis you don't want to scale along, and thus scaling along the other two; So if you pressed <kbd>S</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, you would scale along Y and Z, but not X. This, however, only applies in the 3D View, not in the UV/Image Editor, as there are only two dimensions.

Comment: is there a shortcut to scale automatically to fill the UV edit window?

i don't mean scale to bounds. i mean when you do any UV projection, say cylinder, it comes up in the UV window and i have to do SX, SY to get it to fit the box. i'd like to do that automatically. is that possible?

thx

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and limit the scale to any axis with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> (or <kbd>Z</kbd> in 3D view).